# Can external HDD be larger than 2TB with MBR?

Tags: partitioning, mbr

I want to expand my media player’s storage with a 4 TB external HDD. The media player does not support GPT, however, just MBR.

I read that MBR only allows a maximum partition size of 2 TB. Are external HDDs any different in that regard?

Can I use external HDDs larger than 2 TB with my media player?

Could I, for example, partition the HDD in two different 2TB partitions so the device could access them separately?

Does the external HDD even need MBR as boot record or could I use GPT on it for it to still work with the OS?

Comment: No, MBR (the whole scheme, not just a single partition!) really is limited to 2 TB—with 512-byte sectors, that is. Also, he already said what he’s using. It’s a proprietary media player device.

Comment: @Ramhound the os is eminents media OS booted from a separate flashchip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With MBR, the maximum *disk size* is 2 TB. It can work on larger disks, too, but you won’t be able to use anything beyond the first 2 TB. However, this only applies to disks with 512-byte sectors (because, incidentally, 512 byte * 2^32 = 2 TB).

There are external disks available which present themselves as disks with 4096-byte sectors. On these disks, MBR can support up to 16 TB. There might also be real (without 512-byte sector emulation) 4K disks by now.

There is, however, the matter of your device. On its [info page](http://www.eminent-online.com/nl/product/954/em7280-hdmedia---hd-media-player---voor-interne-harddisk.html), there are some important points:

> Hard disk: Internal 3.5 inch SATA (NTFS/FAT32, SATA I & II, **up-to 2Tb**, **no GPT**)

While they write “internal”, there’s no reason this wouldn’t apply to *every* disk you connect to the player. After all, the player isn’t booting from this disk. So it definitely doesn’t support GPT.

You may, however, be able to use one of the aforementioned 4K disks.

Comment: Okay thanks! I think u made a typo with 512*2^32, which should be 2TB instead of 4 i think. Except for that thanks for ur fast answer.

Comment: 512*(2^32) would be for 32-bit architecture, right? So for 64 bit architecture, would it be 512*(2^64) ??

Comment: @GypsyCosmonaut No. This is about a specific data structure, the MBR. It is not related to the CPU architecture at all.

Comment: Where does the number 32 come from then? What does it represent?

Comment: The size (in bits) of the partition length data field in the [MBR data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record#PTE). The unit is sectors.

Comment: 4K native drives were available for quite a long time: [How can a MBR formatted hard drive exceed 1.81 TiB capacity?](https://superuser.com/q/852475/241386), [MBR partition with more than 2 TB](https://superuser.com/q/562331/241386)