# Installing Windows 8 on Macbook Pro

Tags: mac, windows-8

So, I've recently bought Windows 8 and am attempting to install in on my mac now that Apple has officially updated Bootcamp to support Windows 8, but here is my issue.

I'm getting this error: `Windows can't be installed on this storage device. The chosen harddisk contains a MBR-partition-table. Windows can only be installed on GPT-harddisks on EFI-systems.` I installed the preview with no problem, but now that I'm trying to install the actual thing, I get all sort of errors. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your MacBook is running a drive which has been partitioned using the [MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) mechanism, not the newer [GUID partition table (GPT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) mechanism which has superseded it.  That's pretty unusual, unless your MacBook is fairly old or the drive is fairly old.  (For more information about the differences, see [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/324525/what-are-the-differences-between-mbr-vs-gpt-vs-any-other-partition-scheme)).

If there is nothing else on this drive, then the easiest approach would simply be to repartition the drive.  Here's a [step-by-step guide](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/ss/windows-8-clean-install-part-1_15.htm) which shows you how to change the partition structure during Windows 8 installation.

If the drive has other content (for example, a Mac OS X partition you boot into) then you really ought to consider running Windows 8 as a Virtual Machine within OS X.  I do that (in fact, I am typing this on a MacBook Pro right now running Windows 8 in VMWare Workstation).  The virtualization hardware support is so good these days that you won't notice much, if any, speed difference.

Comment: I use Parallels and am STUNNED at how well a virtualized environment works.  You are absolutely correct.  I see a 3% change in one CPU when I run Win7 in Parallels 8.

Comment: VMWare, is a viable option, but for aesthetic reasons, I'd rather dual boot. I'm just weird like that. My partition is GPT, but when I restart I get no bootable devices found, so I restart my mac and choose the efi, boot in order to install, but I think that mac has a certain way of booting that I'm unfarmiliar with.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

At the very bottom of the window you will see the "Partition Map Scheme"  That needs to be set to GUID Partition Scheme (like in the picture above).

Comment: It is already set to GUID Partition Table

Comment: You are actually booting up in OS X, going in to Boot Camp, and following the instructions it provides to install Win8, correct?  I'm not asking this to be an a55, just to make sure that we are agreeing on your method of install...

Comment: Yes, I did, but instead of booting from a USB, I just burned it to a disc to install.